# google map javascript direction service returns zero result with TRANSIT mode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The following code returns status "OK":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsService.route({
        origin: {lat:35.059280, lng:135.753},
        destination: {lat:34.981117, lng:135.748},
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    }, function(response, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

The following code returns status "ZERO RESULTS":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsService.route({
        origin: {lat:35.059280, lng:135.753},
        destination: {lat:34.981117, lng:135.748},
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
    }, function(response, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

The only difference is the travelMode.
But when I manually search google map, I did get couple of routing directions in TRANSIT mode.

https://www.google.com.tw/maps/dir/35.05928,135.753/34.98117,135.748/@35.0193556,135.7110872,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e3

Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK with your code. You just need to check if transit mode data is available in Maps APIs for given city.

I understand you search route in Kyōto. Please check the coverage for Transit directions on https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage

It looks like Kyōto is not in the list and transit data isn't available via Maps APIs.

Comment: Sorry, after review the link twice, I am confused. From the link in your answer, I only see Japan but not Kyoto. As for Japan, the only one not covered is bike route. How do you know the coverage for Kyoto? Thanks!

Comment: Once on the page click the link 'Public Transit'. There you will see the public transport coverage on per city basis.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see the public transit link. Maybe it's because my location is in Taiwan and I was relocated to Taiwan-specific page.